# Create DataFrame from case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have read other related questions but I do not find the answer.

I want to create a `DataFrame` from a case class in Spark 2.3. Scala 2.11.8.

Code

```
package org.XXX

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("test")
      .getOrCreate()

    case class Employee(Name:String, Age:Int, Designation:String, Salary:Int, ZipCode:Int)
    val EmployeesData = Seq( Employee("Anto",   21, "Software Engineer", 2000, 56798))
    val Employee_DataFrame = EmployeesData.toDF

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Here is what I [tried](http://www.javachain.com/spark-data-frame-using-case-class) in spark-shell:

```
case class Employee(Name:String, Age:Int, Designation:String, Salary:Int, ZipCode:Int)
val EmployeesData = Seq( Employee("Anto",   21, "Software Engineer", 2000, 56798))
val Employee_DataFrame = EmployeesData.toDF
```

Error

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog overrides final method alterDatabase.(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/catalog/CatalogDatabase;)V
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:172)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataset(SparkSession.scala:470)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataset(SQLContext.scala:377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.localSeqToDatasetHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:228)
```

Comment: Code is OK, where do you try? spark-shell? IDE? Could you add information about how do you initialize SparkSession. What scala version do you have?

Comment: yes, the error that you are getting seems unrelated to me

Answer (score 5):

There is no issue in the piece of code you copied from the link shared, as error explains it's something else (exact code copy result in my run below).

```
case class Employee(Name:String, Age:Int, Designation:String, Salary:Int, ZipCode:Int)
val EmployeesData = Seq( Employee("Anto",   21, "Software Engineer", 2000, 56798))
val Employee_DataFrame = EmployeesData.toDF
Employee_DataFrame.show()
```

Employee_DataFrame:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, Age: integer ... 3 more fields]'

```
+----+---+-----------------+------+-------+
|Name|Age|      Designation|Salary|ZipCode|
+----+---+-----------------+------+-------+
|Anto| 21|Software Engineer|  2000|  56798|
+----+---+-----------------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4):

To be able to use implicit conversion to DataFrame you have to **import spark.implicits._** like :

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("test")
      .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
```

This way the conversion should work.

In case you are using Spark Shell this is not needed as the Spark session is already created and the specific conversion functions imported.

Comment: However the error suggests that you mixed up some dependencies. Check the version of your dependencies and if they are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the case class outside the function. Something like this.

```html
object TransformDfExample {
  case class Employee(Name: String, Age: Int, Designation: String, Salary: Int, ZipCode: Int)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("")
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000")
      .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    import spark.implicits._
        val EmployeesData = List(Employee("Anto", 21, "Software Engineer", 2000, 56798))
    val Employee_DataFrame = EmployeesData.toDF
    Employee_DataFrame.show()
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```html
+----+---+-----------------+------+-------+
|Name|Age|      Designation|Salary|ZipCode|
+----+---+-----------------+------+-------+
|Anto| 21|Software Engineer|  2000|  56798|
+----+---+-----------------+------+-------+
```